# React native unable to download template

Tags: react-native

Command

```
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

Output

```
✔ Downloading template
✖ Copying template
error Error: Couldn't find the "/var/folders/8x/y10dxy554tzb5d5d2tv_rffh0000gn/T/rncli-init-template-c131XZ/node_modules/react-native/template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. Please make sure the template is valid. Read more: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template.
Error: Error: Couldn't find the "/var/folders/8x/y10dxy554tzb5d5d2tv_rffh0000gn/T/rncli-init-template-c131XZ/node_modules/react-native/template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. Please make sure the template is valid. Read more: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template
    at createFromTemplate (/Users/rmunoz/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:131:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/rmunoz/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:184:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/rmunoz/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:106:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I checked the /var/ directory and /T/rncli-init-template-c131XZ/node_modules/react-native/template.config.js does NOT exist. I tried looking online for the template to just make it myself but i could not find it, i don't really even know where to look.

I followed the github link but i obviously do not want to create a custom template.

I did follow the documentation to install xcode cli tools and the correct version of ruby 2.7.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a warning at the top of [the instructions you're following](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/init.md#using-npx-utility):

> Note: If you have both `yarn` and `npm` installed on your machine, React Native CLI will always try to use `yarn`, so even if you use `npx` utility, only `react-native` executable will be installed using `npm` and the rest of the work will be delegated to `yarn`. You can force usage of `npm` adding `--pm npm` flag to the command.

You need to re-run your command with `--pm npm`:

```bash
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject --pm npm
```

Comment: warn Flag --npm is deprecated and will be removed soon. In the future, please use --pm npm instead.

Answer (score 3):

Today, in 2024, the answer to this question is:
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject --pm npm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).